# InnoScript Run PowerShell Commands

Tags: mysql, windows, powershell, inno-setup

I am trying to run a powershell command, I know that powershell command works fine but when I try to run it using innoscript it opens up powerscript and shows the command but doesn't seem to run it.

I am basically trying to change the text in a MySql config text file.

This is my code

```
Filename: powershell.exe; Parameters: "-NoExit {{(Get-Content \""{code:GetConfigPath}\my.ini\"") | ForEach-Object {{ $_ -replace \""max_connections=[0-9]+$\"", \""max_connections=10000\"" } | Set-Content \""{code:GetConfigPath}\my.ini\""}"; StatusMsg: CHANGING MAX CONNECTIONS; Description: CHANGING MAX CONNECTIONS; Flags: runascurrentuser
```

If I use the ShellExec flag it says that PSReadLine is not available

screenshot of powershell
[image]

Comment: Did you mean PSReadLine?

Comment: Yes that is what I meant

Comment: Try with `-NoProfile` as the very first parameter

Answer (score 1):

I get the same results, when I execute your command directly. So your question has nothing to do with Inno Setup.

[image]

---

To make the command working, just remove the outermost brackets.

```
Filename: powershell.exe; Parameters: "-NoExit (Get-Content \""{code:GetConfigPath}\my.ini\"") | ForEach-Object {{ $_ -replace \""max_connections=[0-9]+$\"", \""max_connections=10000\"" } | Set-Content \""{code:GetConfigPath}\my.ini\"""; StatusMsg: CHANGING MAX CONNECTIONS; Description: CHANGING MAX CONNECTIONS; Flags: runascurrentuser
```

Comment: Without the brackets it doesn't do the command property and deletes almost all the text in the my.ini file

Comment: OK, I've misplaced brackets in my answer. It's fixed now. But my recommendation still holds, just remove the outermost brackets.

Comment: To explain why this is happening, the original PowerShell code defines a new ScriptBlock, but does not execute it or assign it to a variable.  Thus it becomes an object that goes down the pipeline.  It then hits `Out-Default` and goes to the formatting engine which converts it to a string to be printed on screen.

Removing the outer brackets defines a series of commands to actually execute.